# RX Java Обьеденение двух Observable

Tags: android, rxjava

Есть вот такой код.

Здесь мы получаем местоположение телефона и показываем пользователю это на карте.

```
Single<Task<Location>> taskSingle = Single.create(singleSubscriber -> mMapHandler.getCurrentLocation(activity));

        Disposable getCurrentLocationDisposable = taskSingle
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(locationTask -> locationTask.addOnSuccessListener(this::updateMap));
```

А здесь мы должны получить название города в котором пользователь находится и передать эту строку для запроса погоды по названию города.

```
        Disposable getWeatherDisposable = mModel.getWeatherData(city)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(this::updateUi,
                        this::handleError);
```

Я никак не могу сообразить как это сделать. Как сделать получить данные из первого Observable и на основании этих данных запустить второй Observable.

Попробовал вот так, но есть проблема

```
Disposable disposable = taskSingle
                .flatMap(new Function<Task<Location>, SingleSource<? extends WeatherData>>() {
                    @Override
                    public SingleSource<? extends WeatherData> apply(Task<Location> locationTask) throws Exception {
                        locationTask.addOnSuccessListener(location -> {
                            updateMap(location);
                            String single = getCurrentLocationCity(activity, location);
                        });
                        return //вот тут я не знаю как вернуть значение;
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe();
```

как мне передать результат дальше по цепочке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, вы используете `Task API` из Google Play Services.

Если это так, то не совсем понятно зачем вам здесь `RxJava`, если только ради многопоточности, то `task` и так выполняется в другом потоке. Вы также могли бы запуск запроса погоды реализовать в функции обратного вызова `addOnSuccessListener` task'а примерно так:

```
mMapHandler.getCurrentLocation(activity)
        .addOnSuccessListener(location -> {
                updateMap(location);
                String city = getCurrentLocationCity(activity, location);
                Disposable getWeatherDisposable = mModel.getWeatherData(city)
                  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                  .subscribe(this::updateUi,
                          this::handleError);
            }

        );
```

Но если, все-таки нужно использовать `RxJava` при запросе местоположения, то согласно [документации по `Task API`](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks), если ваш код уже выполняется в другом потоке (в фоне), то вы можете выполнить `task` синхронно (заблокировав выполнение кода) и избежать обратного вызова. В вашем случае, так как `taskSingle` планируется запускать в другом потоке, то он бы выглядел так:

```
Single<Location> taskSingle = Single.create(singleSubscriber -> Tasks.await(mMapHandler.getCurrentLocation(activity)));
Disposable getCurrentLocationDisposable = taskSingle
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(location -> {
                    updateMap(location);
                    // выполнение запроса погоды для города location
                 });
```